# Number of connected partitions (or labelings) in a grid graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, partition-problem

Let $G$ be a 2D lattice graph (undirected) of size $W\times H$. Each "inner" vertex has $4$ adjacent vertices, whereas "boundary" vertices have $2$ or $3$ adjacent vertices, whether they are at a corner or border. Here is an example with $W=4$ and $H=3$ :

$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
O & - & O & - & O & - & O\\
| &   & | &   & | &   & |\\
O & - & O & - & O & - & O\\
| &   & | &   & | &   & |\\
O & - & O & - & O & - & O\\
\end{array}$$

I wish to partition $G$ into $n$ subgraphs. Each vertex can be labeled with an integer from $1$ to $n$. I would like to count the number of possible "connected labelings" of $G$, as a function of $W$, $H$ and $n$.
In image processing, we would call this a segmentation, with non-empty and connected regions.
In my "connected labeling", two properties should be verified :

1. non-emptiness : have at least one vertex per label
2. connection : each subgraph made up of vertices labeled i should be connected

Without any constraint, there are $n^{WH}$ possible labelings. If we add the non-emptiness constraint, we should remove the labelings having only 1, 2, ... n-1 labels, which gives
$$n^{WH} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {n\choose k}k^{WH}$$
But, then, how to handle the connectedness constraint?